# Annihilator, vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\dim_K(V)\geq 1$ and $M \subset V$ with $\emptyset \neq M \subsetneq V$.
Can $M$ exist with $M^0=V$? $M^0$ refers to the annihilator of $M$ and $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: $M^o$ is a subspace of the dual space of $V$ that is $V^*$. Did you mean $M^o=V^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** the spoiler was wrong! The set $M$ is assumed to be non empty but it could very well be zero.

**Hint:** note that your question amounts to proving or disproving that given a non-empety subset $M \subsetneq V$ there exists $\varphi \in V^\ast$ and $m \in M$ such that $\varphi(m) \neq 0$.

> This shows that indeed no such $M$ exists if $M \neq 0$. Since $M$ is non empty, we can fix $x \in M$. The set $\{x\}$ is linearly independent and so it can be extended to a basis $B = \{x,y_1, \cdots, y_n\}$ of $V$. Now take $\varphi$ to be the first element of the dual basis, i.e. define $\varphi : V \to \Bbbk$ such that $\varphi(y_j) = 0, \varphi(x) = 1$.